# SSAS Tabular Filter Pivot in Excel from list

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, powerpivot, dax

I have a basic Tabular Cube and my users will be connecting to the cube from Excel via pivot tables.
Is there any way to have a dynamic filter based off a list that the user can manage in Excel outside of the cube?
In other words sheet1 would be a live pivot query and sheet2 would be a list of values which would filter the pivot.

Thanks...

Comment: You can use VBA to perform filters on a pivot, however you have to be aware about the constraints in your Cube model. Also note Excel includes some formulas for querying SSAS Cubes... check this [1](http://www.decisivedata.net/blog/using-excel-formulas-to-query-ssas-cubes) and [2](https://www.powerpivotpro.com/2010/06/using-excel-cube-functions-with-powerpivot/). In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294199/mdx-syntax-for-dax-measures-calculated-with-average/40768331#40768331) the OP needed something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If a VBA or `=CUBEVALUE` approach Alejandro [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294199/mdx-syntax-for-dax-measures-calculated-with-average/40768331#40768331) doesn't suit your users and they would prefer a UI then install the free OLAP PivotTable Extensions and use the [Filter List](https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Filter%20List&referringTitle=Home) feature. It doesn't let you use the values in an Excel sheet as an automatic filter, but you can copy and paste a list in to the Filter List dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Cubemeasure/CubeValue approach as mentioned by Alejandro.
I'm currently trying to get CUBESET to work as Cubemember is too low a grain and I only need the aggregate values - I'll repost when I have it working.
Thanks All.